# Could a Lion Turtle give Sokka bending?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, the-legend-of-korra

So I thought it was a bit odd, the entire power to "energy-bend" and give people bending. In the show Legend of Korra

> Wang is given fire by a Lion Turtles, and is given various other elements from 
>  the others that existed.

This doesn't explain people with the lack of bending, as

> Wan's people and friends all gain firebending powers to live in the wild.

It got me thinking about non-benders, and their lack of bending.

**Are they descended from some people who never gained bending from the Lion Turtles? Could they be given the ability to firebend by the remaining Lion Turtle (and completely remove the plotline of Season 1 of LoK)?**

Comment: It's definitely not just ancestry. Sokka's sister Katara is a water-bender. As another potentially relevant example, the brothers Mako and Bolin from TLOK each have different bending ability (fire and earth, respectively).

Comment: To be clear, it's not just Sokka but all non-benders?

Comment: @svick If you want to go even further, the TWINS from the Aunt Woo episode?!?

Comment: @CreationEdge Indeed, but I specifically ask about Sokka because he complains about it in the series. I added Legend of Korra because non-bending is a "problem" in general. I'll change the question just slightly to match, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've seen all of the Legend of Aang and the first two books of Legend of Korra.
As far as I can tell, bending comes from the Lion turtles; they give it to people. Another way is by the harmonic convergence. 
If you look at Bumi, Aang's oldest son, he was born a nonbender even though he was the son of Aang and Katara. Thus, bending is not directly passed on from parents to their children. If I recall correctly, Katara's parents were nonbenders too. So whether or not it is inherited seems to be kind of random.
I don't see why the Lion turtle shouldn't be able to bestow bending upon other humans. 
But bending is odd. Take a look at Mako and Bolin. Same parents, as far as I know, yet different bending powers.

Comment: I belive Mako and Bolin had one parent that was a fire bender and one that was an earth. That was why Bolin could lava bend